# Looping through coordinates, adding new coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates

Ok I am using Flotr2 to make a graph, and apparently the only way to get the curved line between two coordinates is to add a new coordinate every say 0.1, between two different coordinates.

So. I have data = [[1, 2], [2, 3]];

Where it is [[x, y], [x, y]].

How would i loop through the coordinates, and do like.. [1, 2], [1.1. 2.1], [1.2, 2.2] etc..?

I need to do this in jquery or javascript, doesnt matter which one.

Comment: Use a for-loop to iterate from x_min to x_max, adding 0.1 with each iteration. You can then generate coordinates by pushing a new array composed of the current values for x and y to your current array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for-loop to iterate from x_min to x_max, adding 0.1 with each iteration. You can then generate coordinates by pushing a new array composed of the current values for x and y to your current array.

```
var data = [[1, 2], [2, 3]];
var x_min = data[0][0];
var x_max = data[1][0];
var initial = data[0];
var iteration = 0.1;

data.length = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < (x_max-x_min); i+=iteration) {
   data.push([initial[0]+i, initial[1]+i]);
}

​console.log(data)​
```